# useMemo computationally expensive calculations

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

I've created a sandbox using useMemo to optimize a mock expensive function follow Kent C Dodds example from this [post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback#computationally-expensive-calculations). Memoisation doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-rfphn?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: In the example , useMemo is redundant

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can think that Memoisation of useMemo has only one item, useMemo's function will be called when dependency has any change. In your example, child will render when duration changed, but when duration changed useMemo will also be recalled. Remove the useMemo's dependency, you can see useMemo works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**useMemo() is actually working correctly in your code**

You have:

`const value = useMemo(() => wait(duration), [duration]);`

`useMemo()` recalculate its value every time any of the values from its dependency changes, and you have `[duration]` inside your dependency array which change every time, you click the `setDuration()` button.

---

If you want to see `useMemo()` works, make the component re-render without changing its dependency.

Something like this: [useMemo()](https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-forked-pgb31)

Comment: Thanks for the example. That makes sense. In the article, it states: "On top of that React also stores previous values given the inputs and will return the previous value given the same previous inputs. That's memoization at work.". 

Am I incorrect in understanding that as "If you pass in the same value(s) as previous values to useMemo, it will return the previously calculated result".

Comment: You are correct, If the next dependency value(s) are `same` as the previous ones, the callback inside useMemo() won't run. `Same` here meaning that they have the same reference (===).

Comment: I see what you mean. I was assuming it remembered all previous values. But it looks like it only remembers the most recent previous value.

Comment: Yeah, So the key is `one` not `all` even though it sounds heavy in terms of memory. Great finds, btw